# Error: Type with name "AuthorYaml" does not exists - gatsby-casper starter

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typeerror, gatsby

I'm trying to build a gatsby website based on gatsby-casper starter but I am getting a hard to debug error related to the graphql schema. The error I get is this:

```
Error: Type with name "AuthorYaml" does not exists

- TypeStorage.js:44 SchemaComposer.get
[Physicc-blog]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeStorage.js:44:13

- TypeMapper.js:585 ThunkComposer._thunk
[Physicc-blog]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeMapper.js:585:34

- ThunkComposer.js:20 ThunkComposer.get ofType [as ofType]
[Physicc-blog]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ThunkComposer.js:20:34

- ThunkComposer.js:46 ThunkComposer.getType
[Physicc-blog]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ThunkComposer.js:46:17

- ListComposer.js:22 ListComposer.getType
[Physicc-blog]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ListComposer.js:22:49

- ObjectTypeComposer.js:348 ObjectTypeComposer.getFieldConfig
[Physicc-blog]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ObjectTypeComposer.js:348:18

- index.js:220 forEach
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/extensions/index.js:220:48

- Array.forEach

- index.js:215 forEach
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/extensions/index.js:215:8

- Array.forEach

- index.js:211 processFieldExtensions
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/extensions/index.js:211:32

- schema.js:226 processTypeComposer
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/schema.js:226:11

- schema.js:200 map
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/schema.js:200:7

- Array.map

- schema.js:199 updateSchemaComposer
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/schema.js:199:50

- schema.js:64 buildSchema
[Physicc-blog]/[gatsby]/src/schema/schema.js:64:3
```

I have used

```
gatsby new my-gatsby-project https://github.com/scttcper/gatsby-casper
```

to initialize the project. I'm unable to figure out why this error is being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... that starter ([gatsby-casper](https://github.com/scttcper/gatsby-casper)) has a reference to `AuthorYaml` in the `gatsby-node.js` at [line 105](https://github.com/scttcper/gatsby-casper/blob/master/gatsby-node.js#L105):

```
  allAuthorYaml {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
```

So if you haven't defined that node, your GraphQL query is not able to run, hence the code is breaking.

Pulling more the thread, `allAuthorsYaml` is a node created by [`gatsby-transformer-yaml`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-yaml/), present in `gatsby-config.js` ([line 64](https://github.com/scttcper/gatsby-casper/blob/master/gatsby-config.js#L64)):

```
'gatsby-transformer-yaml',
```

And mapped in [line 11](https://github.com/scttcper/gatsby-casper/blob/master/gatsby-config.js#L11) of the same `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
  mapping: {
    'MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.author': 'AuthorYaml',
  },
```

This means that you are creating an `AuthorYaml` node from the author field in your markdown `frontmatter`.

So, if your markdown `frontmatter` doesn't contain an author reference, your code will break. It can be easily fixed by setting the proper author in the markdown file, or just by removing `allAuthorYaml` query node from the `gatsby-node.js` and all the related references to them like:

```
  // Create author pages
  const authorTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/author.tsx');
  result.data.allAuthorYaml.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/author/${_.kebabCase(edge.node.id)}/`,
      component: authorTemplate,
      context: {
        author: edge.node.id,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

From [line 188](https://github.com/scttcper/gatsby-casper/blob/master/gatsby-node.js#L188) from `gatsby-node.js` file.

The same applies for `authorTemplate` since you won't be passing any author in the context your `authorTemplate` query will fail too.

Comment: The thing is that `gatsby-node.js` and `gatsby-config.js` are very different in my cloned local copy. When I cloned the git repo instead, I was able to compile everything smoothly. It didn't have the `allAuthorsYaml` node missing. Thanks for the explanation.